# Big O notation and polynomials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I often see that the following polynomial can be written as such:

$f(x) = 6x^4+3x^3+O(x^2)$

where the big O collects all the lower order terms.

Yet, I also see this sometimes:

$f(x) = 6x^4+7x^9+O(x^{11})$

where the big O collects higher order terms.

How does this even make sense? For $f(x)$ to be in $O(g(x))$ doesn't it need to grow at least as fast as $g(x)$ at super large values of $x$?

Comment: Probably the second case is about $x$ in the neighbourhood of $0$, not $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write something like:

$f(x) \in 6x^4+3x^3+O(x^2)$ as $x \to \infty$

$f(x) \in 6x^4+3x^3+O(x^{11})$ as $x \to 0$

There are two points here. Firstly the Big-O notations denote classes of functions, not a single function, and it is a misleading abuse of notation to use "$=$" between a single function and a class. Don't forget that $O(x) - O(x) = O(x)$, not $O(x) - O(x) = 0$. Secondly, we cannot talk about limiting behaviour without specifying the region we are concerned with, just like it is meaningless to write "$\frac{2^n}{n^2} \to \infty$" just like that without specifying anything about $n$.

Comment: I wouldn't say the equality notation is abusive here. Yes, Big-O denotes a class of functions. However, computer scientists are really the ones that use this notation. When deriving runtime complexity, it is common to see $T(n) = f(x) + O(g(x))$. Of course, the goal is to find a nice asymptotic bound for $T(n)$. I would say that the notation is clear, and so not too abusive. But this is just my opinion. :-)

Comment: @ml0105: I agree that "=" is widely used but it forces readers to have to pass it through another layer of interpretation. When I teach first-year undergraduate students I suspect that there is more difficulty in the myriad of notations than in the actual logical content itself. So I would prefer to use one consistent notation throughout different topics, and perhaps mention that historically or conventionally people do use alternative notations. Furthermore, Big-O notation is used in many other areas like complex analysis, where precision is very important as it is easy to make mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on what  Bernard said:

In general,
big-Oh and little-Oh terms
are smaller than
the explicit terms
that they are together with.

When you have
$f(x) = 6x^4+3x^3+O(x^2)$,
this intends
$x^2$
to be smaller than
$x^3$ and $x^4$.
This holds when
$x$ is *large*,
so when
$x \to \infty$.

When you have
$f(x) = 6x^4+7x^9+O(x^{11})
$,
this intends
$x^{11}$
to be smaller than
$x^9$ and $x^4$.
This holds when
$x$ is *small*,
so when
$x \to 0$.

Comment: What you say is true but very misleading... It gives people the impression that we can afford to be imprecise and expect to be understood. If we take this 'general convention', we cannot do any serious manipulation using asymptotic expressions at all.

Comment: I disagree. Controlled imprecision can be very useful. "I'll be there in about an hour." "That sum is 1 plus terms that go to zero."

Comment: Well if the context is clear it's alright of course, but many times people don't make the context clear and don't get that it is important.

Comment: And unfortunately that's precisely why we get tons of questions here about imprecise notation including Big-O notation!

Answer (score 1):

The Big-O terms in the function definitions are place-holders. They are just saying that there is a function that is asymptotically bounded above by $x^{11}$. The $O(x^{11})$ isn't collecting higher order terms. A function $g(x)$ containing $x^{12}$ for example, wouldn't be a part of $f(x)$.

The Big-O notation is commonly used as short-hand for this purpose.

Comment: By the way, "isn't collecting higher order terms" may be a little ambiguous.. If $f(x) = 6x^4+3x^3+12x^{12}+13x^{13}$, then $f(x) \in 6x^4+3x^3+O(x^{11})$ as $x \to 0$. That is what some people may call "collecting".

Comment: If you say as $x \to 0$, then yes, I'd agree. Big-O is defined as a limit towards infinity, though. So based on the definition of Big-O, using $x \to 0$ needs to be clarified.

Comment: No Big-O is not defined as a limit towards infinity. Just because in CS it is obviously the usual case does not mean it is the real definition in general.

Comment: Besides, you should have seen Big-O expressions used everywhere in analysis, such as in Taylor series.

Comment: Big-O: $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ if and only if there exist constants $c, k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $|f(x)| \leq c * |g(x)|$ for all $x \geq k$. It's defined as the function $f(x)$ tends towards infinity. Yes, I've seen them in Taylor Series, Number Theory, Algorithms and Complexity, and elsewhere.

Comment: That is your definition, not necessarily what others use.

Comment: The definition I provided is analogous to the reals: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Well the wikipedia definition explicitly states "as $x \to \infty$", which is because in general Big-O is not confined to when $x \to \infty$.

Comment: In fact, now that I think about it I can't agree with your answer. People often refer to "higher-order approximations" as involving more terms of an asymptotic expansion, and similarly "higher-order terms" as those terms that can be neglected in "lower-order approximations". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_approximation.